# Set WooCommerce checkout billing field postcode default value based on the selected country

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to set a default value in the billing postcode field, depending on the selected country, I have used the following code but it has not worked correctly:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'my_woocommerce_checkout_fields');
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function my_woocommerce_checkout_fields($fields) {
$fields['billing'] = my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields['billing']);
return $fields;
}

function my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields) {

global $woocommerce;
$countries = array( 'CO' );

if ( is_checkout() && in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_country(), $countries ) ){
    
  $fields['billing_postcode']['default'] = '80100';

  $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = TRUE;
  $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;

  return $fields;
 }
}
```

I have to refresh the page to see the changes, and I would like the billing postcode field to update automatically, if the country is 'CO', otherwise the field should be empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Done with the following code found in this forum with a small modification:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_script', 10 );
function custom_checkout_script() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', '#billing_country', function() {
            var location = $('#billing_country option:selected').val();
            if( location == 'CO' ) {
                $('input#billing_postcode').val('80100');
            } else if( location != 'CO' && $('input#billing_postcode').val() == '80100' ) {
                $('input#billing_postcode').val('');
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php
}
```